# Redirect user to intended url after login Reactjs

Tags: routes, react-router, reactjs

I am working on a web app using Reactjs for my front end. I prevented users from accessing some pages excepted they are logged in. My problem is how to allow users access their intended url instead of redirecting them back to the home page which I currently do.

My routes are

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/desired-page" component={requireAuth(DesiredPage)} />
    <Route path="/new-page" component={requireAuth(NewPage)} />
</Switch>
```

My requireAuth.js is

```
export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authenticate extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.addFlashMessage({
          type: 'error',
          text: 'You need to login to access this page'
        });
        this.context.router.history.push('/login');
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }

  Authenticate.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    addFlashMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  Authenticate.contextTypes = {
    router:PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    }
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps, { addFlashMessage })(Authenticate);
}
```

Comment: You mean after they login? You didn't show that part of the code. Inside `if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {` save the URL to some global state (e.g. your redux store). Then on successful login redirect to that page.

Comment: Yes..after they login. I thought of this but how to implement has been a challenge

Comment: Saving the url to a global store and retrieving it has been a major challenge for me. Can you please give a pointer?

Answer (score 5):

So ReactTraining Docs provide you a `location` prop which represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or even where it was.

While navigation to a `Login` route you can mention a state as to from which route you are navigating to Login. You can do that with

- Redirect to
- history.push
- history.replace

To dynamically route, you can pass it with `history.push` like

```
const location = {
  pathname: '/login'
  state: { from: 'Main' }
}

history.push(location)
```

In your case it will be

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authenticate extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.addFlashMessage({
          type: 'error',
          text: 'You need to login to access this page'
        });
        const location = {
            pathname: '/login'
            state: { from: {pathname: '/Main'} }
        }
        this.props.history.push(location);
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }

  Authenticate.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    addFlashMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  Authenticate.contextTypes = {
    router:PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    }
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps, { addFlashMessage })(withRouter(Authenticate));
}
```

Now while Re-directing back after login you can access this param with

```
var {from} = this.props.location.state || {from: {pathname: '/'}}
this.props.history.push(from)
```

> NOTE: When you want to make use of `history` object from prop make
> sure to wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried implementing but I still get same result i.e it redirects me back to the  home page which I have before instead of the desired page which I want to access as a user

Comment: @Dayvino, so the page that user wants to access, you will be redirecting from that page itself to login for the user if he is not loggedIn. So are you setting the  `state: { from: {pathname: '/yourCurrentPageRoute'} }`

Comment: Let me explain.. I am on the home page, when I make a request to say Products page, I am redirected to login [if I am not authenticated] in order to get access to the Products page. When I login, I will like to continue the flow to the Products page[because of good UX] and not back to the home page which I currently implement with the above code. Even when I tried your code, I am still redirected to the home page instead of the desired page (Products page) that I will like to access. I am new to React so forgive my naivety

Comment: Exactly so you will be redirecting to login from Products page, you need to redirect like `const location = {
  pathname: '/login'
  state: { from: 'Products' }
}

this.props.history.push(location)` So that you know from where you were redirected and can redirect back

Comment: However, I already have in my login component, redirect to the home page when a user logs in.  `this.props.loginAction(this.state).then(
        (response) => {
          this.context.router.history.push('/');`
        })

Comment: Right, but you need to do that from the page the user is trying to access or pass it as a  prop somehow from the main component so that you can redirect back to the appropriate page

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me on a set up with server side authentication is as follows:

This uses react-route v4.

The App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
   Route,
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import PrivateRoute from './auth/auth'; // ** important
import Header from './pages/common/header/';
import HomePage from './pages/home/';
import SearchPage from './pages/search';
import AdminPage from './pages/admin';
import Logout from './pages/common/logout/';
import AccountPage from './pages/account/';
import Login from './pages/common/login/';

const Root = ({ store }) => {
return(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
                <Router> 
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Switch>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/account" component={AccountPage} />
                            <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
                            <Route path="/search/:root?/:category?/:subcategory?/:place?" component={SearchPage} />
                            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
</Provider>
)
}

Root.propTypes = {
store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Root;
```

The PrivateRoute component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Redirect,
  withRouter, // ** important so that history is availabe
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLogged: false,
        isAdmin: false,
        loaded: false,
    }
}

componentDidMount ()  {
    this.checkIsLogged();
}

checkIsLogged = () => { ** queries the server for user status, ie, logged in or not
    let check = new Promise(resolve => {
        const last_active_client = localStorage.getItem('last_active') ? localStorage.getItem('last_active') : 0;
        const data = { payload: last_active_client};
        resolve(axios.post('/api-session', data));
    })
    check.then(response => {
        this.setState({
            isLogged: response.data.is_logged,
            isAdmin: response.data.is_admin,
            loaded: true,
        })
    })
}

render () {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    const currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname;

    if (!this.state.loaded) return null;
    if (this.props.path.includes('/admin')) { // handles access to admin
        if (!this.state.isLogged) {
            return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {from: currentLocation}
            }}/>
        } else {
            return (  
                <Route {...rest} 
                    render={props => { 
                        return this.state.isAdmin === true ? (
                            <Component {...props} />
                            ):(
                            <Redirect to='/' />
                            )
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    } else { // access to non admin pages
        return (  
            <Route {...rest} 
                render={props => { 
                    return this.state.isLogged === true ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                        ):(
                        <Redirect to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: {from: currentLocation}
                        }}/>
                        )
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
}


export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

Finally on the Login Component, after user has been successfully logged in:

```
  let { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } } // retrieves the URL set on the PrivateRoute component above
  if (result.payload.data.is_admin) { // checks if user is admin to redirect to admin page
      from = '/admin';
   } 
   this.props.history.push(from); // this will redirect to intended page
```

Answer (score 0):

This is latest in This uses react-route v5.

In my case  I used useLocation in Loading.js and login.js

```js
login.js


import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Jumbotron from "../../components/cards/Jumbotron";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/auth";

export default function Login() {
  // state
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("ryan@gmail.com");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("rrrrrr");
  // hook
  const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  // console.log("location => ", location);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log(data);
      if (data?.error) {
        toast.error(data.error);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(data));
        setAuth({ ...auth, token: data.token, user: data.user });
        toast.success("Login successful");
        navigate(
          location.state ||
            `/dashboard/${data?.user?.role === 1 ? "admin" : "user"}`
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      toast.error("Login failed. Try again.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Jumbotron title="Login" />

      <div className="container mt-5">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control mb-4 p-2"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />

              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control mb-4 p-2"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />

              <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LoadingGIF from "../../images/loading.gif";

export default function Loading({ path = "login" }) {
  // state
  const [count, setCount] = useState(3);
  // hooks
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((currentCount) => --currentCount);
    }, 1000);
    // redirect once count is equal to 0
    count === 0 &&
      navigate(`/${path}`, {
        state: location.pathname,
      });
    // cleanup
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div
      className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      style={{ height: "90vh" }}
    >
      <img src={LoadingGIF} alt="Loading" style={{ width: "400px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And if you console.log location you will see the ouput pathname
[image]